# how to replace "Remove" checkboxes in Ubercart

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ubercart

I'm using Ubercart and I'm customizing the shopping cart.

I would like to replace the check box to select which items to remove with a link "X Remove" which dynamically removes the items (ajax reqeust I guexx) by fading them out:

From this: http://www.designer-daily.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/ubercart.jpg

to this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/removeItem.png

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually found out this module: http://drupal.org/project/uc_pic_cart_block

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and found this, and while it's not exactly what you describe, it might be something to base a solution on:

http://www.ubercart.org/forum/ideas_and_suggestions/13128/single_remove_button_replace_checkbox

I've tried it on my installation, and it works fine with the main cart view - just not in the sidebar block.

Cheers

Paul